# Using selective APIs from Google Play Services in Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, google-play-services, eclipse-adt

In my project I am integrating push notification for that I require  classes from `com.google.android.gms` package.

Is it possible for me to include selected package from whole library?

I am using eclipse. actually there are lot more libraries required, due to which I am facing `65k multidex issue`. Any solution?

Comment: Which are library used in you project?

Comment: You get this error multidex issue because conflicting your other library with google-play-service library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you **really really** want to use the Eclipse to compile this, you need to perform these steps:

1. Have someone with Android studio include your needed Google components as dependency.
2. Kidnap the components from `exploded-aar` Android studio folder and setup the components as your own Eclipse library.

But of course, this is highly not a recommended procedure, but this is for those people who desperately needs it as last resort. This also marks a disclaimer that the kidnapped libraries are already **free from the developer's accountability, because you didn't compile it the right way**.

PS. Did this with Google Maps

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use selective components of the Google Play Services **you will need to switch to Android studio.**

Read this: ([Source](https://developer.android.com/intl/in/tools/help/adt.html#ReferencingLibraryProject))

> **Important:** **Support for the Android Developer Tools (ADT) in Eclipse
>   has ended**, per our announcement. You should migrate your app
>   development projects to Android Studio as soon as possible. For more
>   information on transitioning to Android Studio, see Migrating from
>   Eclipse ADT.

If you still want to continue using eclipse, you'll have to to the hard work yourself - of deleting the unwanted packages/components from the full source code and making sure it compiles and works fine.

**Instructions of setting up selective APIs** can be found on [this page](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup), for android studio. For Eclipse, as the documentation says nothing about setting up selective APIs, you just have to go with the whole set.

Comment: I read some where about editing Maven buil settings manually, to overcome dex error.

Answer (score 0):

NO. you have to migrate your code to **Android Studio**.